# How to add button to word 2007 document, and handle click event with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I:

1. add button to my ms word 2007 document (i would say this would be trivial task, but can't even figure THIS out)
2. handle click event of this button in my VBA script
3. set text of my text control (with tag "text1")

Comment: Do you want a button _in_ the document or on the ribbon?

Comment: In the document. Thanx for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it is what you intended, but to add a button in the document, open [the Developer tab](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ivanwalsh/4015738871/). Click the `Legacy tools` folder (in the Controls group) and click the `Command Button (Active X Control)`. This will put a button in the document and make Word go into design mode.

Double-click the new button and you will enter the VBA editor in the event handler for the button.

Enter code to manipulate the text in TextBox1:

```
TextBox1.Text = "Hi there, VBA master!"
```

Click the design mode button to exit design mode, and you're good to go; click the new button to set the text.

If you meant to add a button in the ribbon? A little more complicated, but not that hard. Leave a comment, and I'm sure we can work it out as well.

Comment: Hello, what if i wanted, instead of TextBox activeX control, use another control - this one: "Text (insert plain text content control)" ? Or this one :Text Form Field ?

Comment: Then you will have to find it in the VBA object model. I don't think you can mix active x controls and the plain text control, though. Could you tell me exactly how your controls are added and I can make a test document - or can you upload your document somewhere, so we could take a look at it?